# Is it possible to rename saved files using mediastore on Android 10?

Tags: android, mediastore

I saved the file as below

I want to change the file name but I want to know how

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename + ".wav");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "/" + "dir" + "/");

Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

File cacheDir = getCacheDir();
File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, filename + ".wav");

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cacheFile);
OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}

outputStream.close();
fis.close();
```

I tried referring to the article below, but without success

Do you have any way? thank you

[Rename file of the Mediastore which is created by app in android 10. Working on Android API 30 but shows error in API 29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63543414/rename-file-of-the-mediastore-which-is-created-by-app-in-android-10-working-on)